# How to set initial value of Django-Select2 widget in Django

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-select2

I am using the django-select2 plugin for a field that lets the user select an institution from a list in the database( driven by AJAX), and it works fine. Here is the field in forms.py

```
    institution = forms.CharField(
    widget = ModelSelect2Widget(
        queryset=Institution.objects.all(),
        attrs={'class': 'form-control'},
        model=Institution,
        search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        max_results=500,
    ),
```

Using the same form, the user can edit/change the previous selected Institute.
For this, however, I would like to set the initial selected value of the field as the previously selected Institution.
This is has caused me a lot of trouble as I am unable to set an initial value for the plugin despite trying many things.

Ideally I am looking to set the initial value of the plugin without using any Javascript(using only Django form options) , something like :

```
current_instutition = Institution.objects.get(user=page_user)
form.fields['institution'].initial = current_institution
```

(the above doesn't work)

I've tried using the Select2 placeholder option to set this manually during page load using the following Javascript code:

```
$("#id_institution").djangoSelect2({
                    placeholder: {
                        id: '123',
                        text: 'My Institution'
                        }
                    });
```

This doesn't seem to do anything at all.(The plugin still loads, with an empty(or no) placeholder) .I'm not sure if django-select2 overrides the manual Select2 options.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try to define a `default` in the model. Select2 can also be updated through JS but it should not. I can show it to you, if you want. I have it somewhere in my project. Alternative is to load `initial_data` when you load the form and define something there.

Comment: Did you got answer??

Answer (score 1):

Your `institution` field is a `CharField`, not a `ModelChoiceField`. That is the reason this line is not correct :

```
form.fields['institution'].initial = current_institution
```